# How can i get the time difference between 2 time strings?

Tags: python, time

```
t1 = '11:19:04' 
t2 = '11:19:07'
```

Being in this format : `H:M:S`

How can i get the time difference between the 2 strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to import datetime module which contains method to convert string time to datetime object, once you have converted your time to datetime object , you can simply substract themtry using this,

```
import datetime
t1 = '11:19:04' 
t2 = '11:19:07'

t1_time=datetime.datetime.strptime(t1,"%H:%M:%S")
t2_time=datetime.datetime.strptime(t2,"%H:%M:%S")
print t2_time-t1_time
0:00:03
```

Comment: Valid answer, no explanation given.

Comment: @Coal_ does it look fine now ?

Comment: thanks, i had the subtraction part right but had no clue I should convert to DateTime object.

Comment: @Carla you can use above code

Comment: I have and it works fine, accepting in 2 mins

Comment: you can mark it as an answer @Carla

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without the datetime module:

```
t1 = '11:19:04' 
t2 = '11:19:07'

def t2s(t):
    return sum(a*b for a, b in zip((int(x) for x in t.split(':')), (3600, 60, 1)))

print(t2s(t1) - t2s(t2))
```

It returns the difference as number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

- Import datetime module:
- Pass the striptime value to the String
- Subtract the 't2' to 't1'
- Demo :

  ```
  import datetime

  t1 = '11:19:04' 'From'
  t2 = '11:19:07' 'Till'

  t1_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%H:%M:%S")
  t2_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, "%H:%M:%S")

  print t2_time - t1_time
  ```